# Google chart not working without throwing an exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

We are using AJAX to display user's statistics - how many emails were sent and received per month (in the current month and the previous 12 months). I'm using Google charts. When I did it without AJAX it worked, but with AJAX Google charts doesn't work - the whole page becomes blank and there is no exception in the console. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var params = {
            "email": "{{ statistics_user_email }}",
            "today_email_statistics_query_job_json": JSON.stringify({{ today_email_statistics_query_job_json|safe }}),
            "this_month_email_statistics_query_job_json": JSON.stringify({{ this_month_email_statistics_query_job_json|safe }}),
            "last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics_query_job_json": JSON.stringify({{ last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics_query_job_json|safe }})
        };

        function try_ajax() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/user/email_statistics',
                data: params,
                success: function(reply) {
                    if (reply.wait === true) {
                        // Try again after 4 seconds.
                        setTimeout(try_ajax, 4000);
                    } else if (reply.ready === true) {
                        function drawTitleSubtitle() {
                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                            data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
                            data.addColumn('number', 'Emails sent');
                            data.addColumn('number', 'Emails received');

                            var rows = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < reply["last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics"].length; i++) {
                                var row = reply["last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics"][i];
                                rows.push([row["month"], row["sent"], row["received"]]);
                            }
                            data.addRows(rows);

                            var options = {
                                'title': 'How Many Vegan Cheeseburgers I Ate Last Night',
                                'width': 400,
                                'height': 300
                            };

                            var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('last-13-month-chart-div'));
                            material.draw(data, options);
                        }

                        $("#today-emails-sent-span").html(reply["today_email_statistics"]["messages_sent"]);
                        $("#today-emails-received-span").html(reply["today_email_statistics"]["messages_received"]);
                        $("#this-month-emails-sent-span").html(reply["this_month_email_statistics"]["messages_sent"]);
                        $("#this-month-emails-received-span").html(reply["this_month_email_statistics"]["messages_received"]);
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTitleSubtitle);
                        $("#please-wait-div").addClass("hidden");
                        $("#email-statistics-div").removeClass("hidden");
                    } else {
                        console.error("AJAX returned unexpected results!", reply);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        try_ajax();
    });
</script>
```

When I comment the following lines, it works without the chart:

```
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTitleSubtitle);
```

The AJAX returned this object once:

```
{"wait": true}
```

And the second time:

```
{"ready": true, "last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics": [{"received": 23, "sent": 2, "month": "2015-10"}, {"received": 15, "sent": 4, "month": "2015-11"}], "this_month_email_statistics": {"messages_received": 15, "messages_sent": 4}, "today_email_statistics": {"messages_received": 0, "messages_sent": 1}}
```

I'm not including the HTML but all the elements exist on the page. Everything works except the chart, which worked before when I didn't use AJAX. What is the problem?

By the way, I only loaded data for this month and the previous month, it's not a bug. In the future we can show the previous 12 months.

I tried to use console.log in the function `drawTitleSubtitle()` but it seems not to be called at all. But there is no `<body>` inside the `<html>` after the AJAX returns the result (the second time it's called).

JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uriwise/Lpsb0tqn/

Comment: Maybe google doesn't like vegan cheeseburgers :)

Comment: @T3H40 It was a Pizza (copied from https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) and I changed it... :-)

Comment: There you go! Problem solved, fixed and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're witnessing ("`drawTitleSubtitle()` [...] seems not to be called") is essentially due to the order of the operations being executed.

Because you're loading the desired packages (`google.load(...)`) and setting the desired callback (`google.setOnLoadCallback(...)`) within `$(document).ready()`, the Google Charts API is unable to reference the desired callback (`drawTitleSubtitle()`) when the packages are eventually loaded.

You should define `drawTitleSubtitle()`, load the desired packages (`google.load(...)`) and set the desired callback `google.setOnLoadCallback(...)` before entering `$(document).ready()`.

Within `$(document).ready()`, `try_ajax()` should then invoke `drawTitleSubtitle()` while passing in the desired Ajax response from `/ajax/user/email_statistics`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I did what Lee suggested and called the `google` functions without waiting for `$(document).ready()`. Here is my code:

**Edit:** I separated my code into 3 separate functions and passed the parameters when calling them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function draw_google_chart(ajax_reply) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Emails sent');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Emails received');

        var rows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ajax_reply["last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics"].length; i++) {
            var row = ajax_reply["last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics"][i];
            rows.push([row["month"], row["sent"], row["received"]]);
        }
        data.addRows(rows);

        var options = {
            'title': 'How Many Vegan Cheeseburgers I Ate Last Night',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
        };

        var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('last-13-month-chart-div'));
        material.draw(data, options);
    }

    function try_ajax(ajax_params) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/user/email_statistics',
            data: ajax_params,
            success: function(ajax_reply) {
                if (ajax_reply.wait === true) {
                    // Try again after 4 seconds.
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        try_ajax(ajax_params);
                    }, 4000);
                } else if (ajax_reply.ready === true) {
                    $("#today-emails-sent-span").html(ajax_reply["today_email_statistics"]["messages_sent"]);
                    $("#today-emails-received-span").html(ajax_reply["today_email_statistics"]["messages_received"]);
                    $("#this-month-emails-sent-span").html(ajax_reply["this_month_email_statistics"]["messages_sent"]);
                    $("#this-month-emails-received-span").html(ajax_reply["this_month_email_statistics"]["messages_received"]);
                    draw_google_chart(ajax_reply);
                    $("#please-wait-div").addClass("hidden");
                    $("#email-statistics-div").removeClass("hidden");
                } else {
                    console.error("AJAX returned unexpected results!", ajax_reply);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function try_ajax_first_time() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var ajax_params = {
                "email": "{{ statistics_user_email }}",
                "today_email_statistics_query_job_json": JSON.stringify({{ today_email_statistics_query_job_json|safe }}),
                "this_month_email_statistics_query_job_json": JSON.stringify({{ this_month_email_statistics_query_job_json|safe }}),
                "last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics_query_job_json": JSON.stringify({{ last_13_months_monthly_email_statistics_query_job_json|safe }})
            };

            try_ajax(ajax_params);
        });
    }

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(try_ajax_first_time);
</script>
```

Please notice that functions `try_ajax` and `draw_google_chart` are always called after `$(document).ready()`, never before (because I need the HTML elements to be in the DOM).

JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uriwise/tp1xhun0/

However, if I call the `google` functions within `$(document).ready()` then it doesn't work, I get the blank page again. I didn't find this documented on Google's website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(try_ajax_first_time);
});
```